# PHP How to color values based on its content for different columns in a function

Tags: php, html

I have a problem with my code of displaying data.
First of all I want ot apologize for my title,  I am not sure how best to formulate my problem.

I want to get the respective values from a table with 4 columns and display them in a table. Based on the respective value, this should be colored differently.
I do this with a bootstrap button.
For example

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" disabled>English</button>
```

The coloring of the buttons differs with using a different class for each value.

The table structue looks like this:

```
| name | q1   | q2   | q3 |  q4 | 
| ---  | ---  | ---  | ---  | ---  |
| test | math | english| |latin
| test2 | english | |biology |french
```

I get the values and put them into the table like this:

```
<table class="table table-striped table-hover table-bordered" id="table-list">
<thead>
<tr><th>Name</th><th>Class</th><th>Course in Q1</th><th>Course in Q2</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php
while ($zeile = mysqli_fetch_array( $db_erg, MYSQLI_ASSOC))
{
?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $zeile['name'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $zeile['q1'];?></td>
<td><?php echo $zeile['q2'];?></td>
<?php } ?> 
</tbody>
</table>
```

The simplest but unattractive coding way would be for me to do a lot if IF operations...

```
if ($zeile['q1']=="english") {$buttonq1='<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" disabled>English</button>';}
if ($zeile['q1']=="math") {$buttonq1='<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" disabled>Math</button>';}
if ($zeile['q4']=="math") {$buttonq4='<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" disabled>Math</button>';}
```

For all values (english, math, latin,...) and all columns (q1-q4).
In the table there would be a echo $buttonq1, echo $buttonq2, ...

But there a got to be a more elegant way. Arround the construct of all IF operations the only little thing that changes is the column (q1,q2,q3,q4).

So I thought of writing a function:

```
function buttonmake ($quart)
{
if ($zeile[$quart]=="english") {$button='<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" disabled>English</button>';}
if ($zeile[$quart]=="math") {$button='<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" disabled>Math</button>';}
if ($zeile[$quart]=="Latin") {$button='<button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" disabled>Latin</button>';}
if ($zeile[$quart]=="") {$button='<a class="btn btn-primary" href="project.php?name='.$name.'&kurs=q1&class='.$class.'" role="button">+ Project</a>';} 
return $button;
}
```

So in my table I would just use it like this:

```
 <td><?php echo buttonmake("q1"); ?></td>
    <td><?php echo buttonmake("q2"); ?></td>
```

But it is not working. I am sure it is because the $zeile is empty, but I do not know how to get it into my function buttonmake..

Hope someone can help me.
Kind regards
Daniel

Comment: The reason you can't access `$zeile` is because it has not been passed to the function. Have a read about "function scoping". You can do 2 things, you can pass `$quart` and `$zeile` to the function, or you can do `global $zeile;` at the start of the function.

Comment: @JacobMulquin Please consider making your comment an answer so it can be marked the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't access `$zeile` is because it has not been passed to the function. Have a read about "function scoping". You can do 2 things, you can pass `$quart` and `$zeile` to the function, or you can do `global $zeile`; at the start of the function.